# can not find a directory with find command

Tags: find

I tried using the command

```
 sudo find / -type d -iname firefox
```

It gave me the following output

```
/usr/share/doc/firefox
/usr/lib/firefox
/home/ashu/.mozilla/firefox
/etc/firefox
```

But i have a directory named firefox located at

> /usr/local/sbin/in

why is not it listed here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably because `/usr/local/sbin/in` (or one of the earlier components) is a symlink to another directory.  `find` doesn't follow symlinks by default; use `-follow` or `-L` to change this, but be aware that it can lead to `find` looping over a directory tree.

Comment: head on actually firefox itself was a symlink to the dir located /etc/firefox4/firefox :P

Answer (score 2):

Is it named just `firefox`? Is does not have version numbers attached to the name? You are not using wildcards in your `find` statement, so a directory called `firefox-3` will not be found.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned geeokosaur was right, you can use this form to include the direct symlink:

```
sudo find / \( -type d -o -xtype d \) -iname firefox
```

Or as geekosaur, suggested already, use find -L as that also deals with the case where (say) /usr/local/sbin is a symbolic link.